# Is there a better functional way to process a vector with error checking?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I'm learning Rust and would like to know how I can improve the code below.

I have a vector of tuples of form `(u32, String)`. The `u32` values represent line numbers and the `String`s are the text on the corresponding lines. As long as all the String values can be successfully parsed as integers, I want to return an `Ok<Vec<i32>>` containing the just parsed `String` values, but if not I want to return an error of some form (just an `Err<String>` in the example below).

I'm trying to learn to avoid mutability and use functional styles where appropriate, and the above is straightforward to do functionally if that was all that was needed. Here's what I came up with in this case:

```
fn data_vals(sv: &Vec<(u32, String)>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, String> {
    sv.iter()
        .map(|s| s.1.parse::<i32>()
                    .map_err(|_e| "*** Invalid data.".to_string()))
        .collect()
}
```

However, the small catch is that I want to print an error message for **every** invalid value (and not just the first one), and the error messages should contain both the line number and the string values in the offending tuple.

I've managed to do it with the following code:

```
fn data_vals(sv: &Vec<(u32, String)>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, String> {
    sv.iter()
        .map(|s| (s.0, s.1.parse::<i32>()
                  .or_else(|e| {
                      eprintln!("ERROR: Invalid data value at line {}:  '{}'",
                                s.0, s.1);
                      Err(e)
                  })))
        .collect::<Vec<(u32, Result<i32, _>)>>() // Collect here to avoid short-circuit
        .iter()
        .map(|i| i.1
             .clone()
             .map_err(|_e| "*** Invalid data.".to_string()))
        .collect()
}
```

This works, but seems rather messy and cumbersome - especially the typed `collect()` in the middle to avoid short-circuiting so all the errors are printed. The `clone()` call is also annoying, and I'm not really sure why it's needed - the compiler says I'm moving out of borrowed content otherwise, but I'm not really sure what's being moved. Is there a way it can be done more cleanly? Or should I go back to a more procedural style? When I tried, I ended up with mutable variables and a flag to indicate success and failure, which seems less elegant:

```
fn data_vals(sv: &Vec<(u32, String)>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, String> {
    let mut datavals = Vec::new();
    let mut success = true;
    for s in sv {
        match s.1.parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(v) => datavals.push(v),
            Err(_e) => {
                eprintln!("ERROR: Invalid data value at line {}:  '{}'",
                          s.0, s.1);
                success = false;
            },
        }
    }
    if success {
        return Ok(datavals);
    } else {
        return Err("*** Invalid data.".to_string());
    }
}
```

Can someone advise me on the best way to do this? Should I stick to the procedural style here, and if so can that be improved? Or is there a cleaner functional way to do it? Or a blend of the two? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a purely functional style, you have to avoid side-effects.
Printing errors is a side-effect. The preferred style would be to return an object of the style:

```
Result<Vec<i32>, Vec<String>>
```

and print the list after the `data_vals` function returns.

So, essentially, you want your processing to collect a list of integers, and a list of strings:

```
fn data_vals(sv: &Vec<(u32, String)>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Vec<String>> {
    let (ok, err): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = sv
        .iter()
        .map(|(i, s)| {
            s.parse()
                .map_err(|_e| format!("ERROR: Invalid data value at line {}: '{}'", i, s))
        })
        .partition(|e| e.is_ok());

    if err.len() > 0 {
        Err(err.iter().filter_map(|e| e.clone().err()).collect())
    } else {
        Ok(ok.iter().filter_map(|e| e.clone().ok()).collect())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = vec![(1, "0".to_string())];
    let r = data_vals(&input);
    assert_eq!(r, Ok(vec![0]));

    let input = vec![(1, "zzz".to_string())];
    let r = data_vals(&input);
    assert_eq!(r, Err(vec!["ERROR: Invalid data value at line 1: 'zzz'".to_string()]));
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db82c101cf7814fa2edbc2d2fd7e657f)

This uses `partition` which does not depend on an external crate.

Comment: Thanks! All the answers here looked good, but I've picked this one because (a) it seems the simplest, and (b) it doesn't need an external crate. I realised that side effects are not purely functional, but it was not clear to me until I saw these answers how to get around it.

Comment: Note that if the other answer hadn't been posted already, I would have probably also recommended using itertools, because it is an awesome addition to the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's what [`partition_map()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from itertools is for:

```
use itertools::{Either, Itertools};

fn data_vals<'a>(sv: &[&'a str]) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Vec<(&'a str, std::num::ParseIntError)>> {
    let (successes, failures): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
        sv.iter().partition_map(|s| match s.parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(v) => Either::Left(v),
            Err(e) => Either::Right((*s, e)),
        });
    if failures.len() != 0 {
        Err(failures)
    } else {
        Ok(successes)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec!["42", "aaaezrgggtht", "..4rez41eza", "55"];
    println!("{:#?}", data_vals(&numbers));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Side effects (`eprintln!`) in an iterator adapter are definitely not "functional". You should accumulate and return the errors and let the caller deal with them.

I would use [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) here. The goal of `fold` is to reduce a list to a single value, starting from an initial value and augmenting the result with every item. This "single value" can very well be a list, though. Here, though, there are two possible lists we might want to return: a list of `i32` if all values are valid, or a list of errors if there are any errors (I've chosen to return `String`s for errors here, for simplicity.)

```
fn data_vals(sv: &[(u32, String)]) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Vec<String>> {
    sv.iter().fold(
        Ok(Vec::with_capacity(sv.len())),
        |acc, (line_number, data)| {
            let data = data
                .parse::<i32>()
                .map_err(|_| format!("Invalid data value at line {}:  '{}'", line_number, data));
            match (acc, data) {
                (Ok(mut acc_data), Ok(this_data)) => {
                    // No errors yet; push the parsed value to the values vector.
                    acc_data.push(this_data);
                    Ok(acc_data)
                }
                (Ok(..), Err(this_error)) => {
                    // First error: replace the accumulator with an `Err` containing the first error.
                    Err(vec![this_error])
                }
                (Err(acc_errors), Ok(..)) => {
                    // There have been errors, but this item is valid; ignore it.
                    Err(acc_errors)
                }
                (Err(mut acc_errors), Err(this_error)) => {
                    // One more error: push it to the error vector.
                    acc_errors.push(this_error);
                    Err(acc_errors)
                }
            }
        },
    )
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[]));
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[(1, "123".into())]));
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[(1, "123a".into())]));
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[(1, "123".into()), (2, "123a".into())]));
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[(1, "123a".into()), (2, "123".into())]));
    println!("{:?}", data_vals(&[(1, "123a".into()), (2, "123b".into())]));
}
```

The initial value is `Ok(Vec::with_capacity(sv.len()))` (this is an optimization to avoid reallocating the vector as we push items to it; a simpler version would be `Ok(vec![])`). If the slice is empty, this will be `fold`'s result; the closure will never be called.

For each item, the closure checks 1) whether there were any errors so far (indicated by the accumulator value being an `Err`) or not and 2) whether the current item is valid or not. I'm matching on two `Result` values simultaneously (by combining them in a tuple) to handle all 4 cases. The closure then returns an `Ok` if there are no errors so far (with all the parsed values so far) or an `Err` if there are any errors so far (with every invalid value found so far).

You'll notice I used the [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push) method to add an item to a `Vec`. This is, strictly speaking, mutation, which is not considered "functional", but because we are moving the `Vec`s here, we know there are no other references to them, so we know we aren't affecting any other use of these `Vec`s.